# Why use plus equals += for event registration?

Tags: c#, language-design, event-programming

In C#, you register an event like:

```
window.onClick += myHandler;
```

But why use this instead of a "register" method that takes your handler and registers it. E.g.:

```
window.registerOnClick(myHandler);
```

The `+=` counters my intuition for at least two reasons:

1. Couldn't somebody use `=` to eliminate past registrations? But more generally:
2. My OOP classes always told me to use getters and setters, not public members.

This came up because I'm writing events in Python and my first thought was to use a `register_handler_on_click(handler)` rather than public member variables.

Comment: "use getters and setters, not public members" is very language-dependent. In e.g. Java it is important because once you choose public member access, you can't later switch to getters/setters without breaking the interface, so it is safer to use getters/setters from the beginning. In Python, thanks to `@property`, you can use what looks like public member ("attribute" in Python) access to implement getters and setters; you don't break the interface by doing it. It's therefore very un-Pythonic to write `getFoo()` and `setFoo()` methods.

Comment: Eric Lippert agrees with you.  See dishonorable mentions on his [Sharp Regrets](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2425867) article.

Comment: @Brian He also takes issue with the for loop syntax in the same category. But everyone knows the for loop syntax is just fine (weird at first, but so is every other notation before you get used to it). C got this one right, which is why every language since has copied it except Python.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you ever try to write something like:

```
window.onClick = myHandler;
```

You will get a compiler error about event handlers only allowed on the right side of a `+=` or `-=`. The C# compiler team was smart enough to recognize that possibility and make it a compiler error.

Events are special types of multi-cast delegates, so therefore you are adding to its invocation list when you `+=` a handler to the event. In this case I think it makes more sense to have `+=` and `-=` to add or subtract event handlers.

I'm not sure who taught your OOP classes, but not everything needs to be reduced to a get/set method. .NET has made get/set type access a lot easier with properties, which include get/set methods in a single construct.

VB.NET uses a slightly different syntax for adding and removing events that are more inline with what you want. They use [`AddHandler` and `RemoveHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yyk8z93(v=vs.90).aspx) methods for adding or removing from the event invocation list, although being a C# programmer I find the VB style "long winded".

Comment: I haven't checked, but if you were to say window.onClick = otherWindow.onClick, wouldn't they evaluate and override the previous delegated subscriptions?

Comment: @zackery.fix - not if `onClick` was an event. That's a compile time error. If they are just _delegates_ then yes, they would.

Answer (score 1):

Events are just specialized delegates. For delegates, `=` *does* eliminate past registrations. Likewise `+` performs functional composition, like many other languages. So `+=` combines those operations into functional append.

Events just happen to limit the other operations, making it a little less intuitive since you don't see where they came from.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: why not?

If you subscribe to the concept that there can be multiple handlers for the same event, then why wouldn't you want the least verbose option?

I know I'm on extremely thin ice disagreeing with C# god Eric Lippert, but it has always seemed very natural syntax to me. If your usual language of choice is Python or another language I can see how this might be less so.

However, I do take his point that it does kind of stick out. I can't think of anywhere else in the language where you're forced to use this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

In C#, you have fields and you also have properties, which are basically encapsulated fields. Properties are commonly implemented using fields (and the language has a shortcut to do it succinctly), but they don't have to be.

So, you can write both:

```
o.Field = 42;
o.Property = 42;
```

But the latter actually compiles to a call to a setter method:

```
o.set_Property(42);
```

Another difference between fields and properties is that properties don't allow some operations, like using `ref`.

---

It's similar with delegates and events: events are encapsulated delegate fields. Events are commonly implemented using delegate fields (and the language has a shortcut to do it succinctly), but they don't have to be.

Also, you can write both:

```
o.DelegateField += Handler;
o.Event += Handler;
```

But the latter actually compiles to a call to an adder method:

```
o.add_Event(Handler);
```

Another difference is that events don't allow you most operations, like assigning or invoking them (with the exception of invoking field-like events from within the declaring class itself).

---

So, now the question is: why can you use `+=` with delegate fields? It's because you can use `+` to combine delegates. This means that `o.DelegateField += Handler;` is just a shorthand for `o.DelegateField = o.DelegateField + Handler;`.

With events, you can't read or assign to them, so the shorthand `+=` syntax is the only option.